# iOS Resizable GUIs with JUCE

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, juce

I'm using the `JUCE` framework to make my first few iOS apps, mostly just proofs of concepts for my Github account for job recruiters.

I've got my first app compiled and working on iOS, but I'm having tons of issues with the GUI.

I can't seem to find the right resolutions to fill the screen.  I'm testing with an iPhone 7 Plus, and I figured I could just type in the resolution of that screen to the Projucer, but it doesn't work correctly.

Then I realize I'd probably just want one that fills the screen automatically, but dont know which function calls to use or where its located in the Projucer (haven't found it yet).

Also, I'm entirely new to `GUI` developing as of December, so I'm still learning all of this.  I would greatly appreciate keeping it simple.  Thank you to anyone who is able to help.

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what exactly you're asking here other than "help how do I write GUI apps". Unless this changes, your question will probably be closed as too broad. Could you please edit your question into something much more specific?

Comment: I'm asking for how to properly size my GUI to match a specific iOS device using JUCE function calls.

Comment: Hello, your question still isn't very specific. You could please make a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? i.e, a single GUI component that you're having problems with, what exactly is happening, and what you expected to happen. Also include what you've tried so far :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in MainComponent.cpp

```
Rectangle<int> area = Desktop::getInstance().getDisplays().getMainDisplay().totalArea;
centreWithSize (area.getWidth(), area.getHeight());
```